# Where can I find a Mozilla Firefox crash log?

Tags: firefox, crash

My Mozilla Firefox crashes frequently (and even major updates don't help). I'd like to investigate the problem. Where can I find the log/report files? There seem to be no option to view the actual crash report when the browser crashes and offers to send a report to Mozilla.

Answer (score 11):

You can access the submitted crashes reports by typing `about:crashes` on the address bar.

The MozillaZine Knowledge Base has an [article about this subject](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Crash_Reporter).

Comment: "You can access the submitted crashes reports" - but I don't want to submit anything anywhere, I just want to view them myself! Tried `about:crashes` right now - it is completely empty even though my Firefox crashes at least 3 times daily.

Comment: I've tried actually submitting a report twice and there is still no thing in "about:crashes".

Comment: Not if Firefox crashes on startup!

Comment: I have the newest version of Firefox and have no about:crashes ("The address isn't valid"). My Firefox crashes so often that I have a script to start it again if it exits with a nonzero exit code.

Comment: ok wow I'm still dealing with Firefox crashing multiple times an hour, sick of it, and here I am, running into a comment I made in February while trying to find the answer.

Comment: What about crashing firefox at startup? You'll even not be able to hit about:config .

Answer (score 7):

The log report files are located at `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Crash Reports\pending` on Windows.

Please note that the DMP files appear to be binary in nature.

Comment: My slashes go the other way, and these files do not exist.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Are you on Mac? If so, it's in `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Crash Reports/pending` instead. I don't know where it is on Linux.

Comment: @SilverWolf Sorry I did not give enough information, for you to guess my OS, it could be any (Well nearly any, I think VMS uses `.`  )

Answer (score 2):

These crashes might be caused by some extensions; try to run it in [Safe Mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_Mode) and see if you get the same problems.

If Safe Mode works correctly, then most likely it is an extension fault; restart it in normal mode, disable all extensions, and restart again; if it runs smoothly, then the crashes were caused by one extension; try to re-enable one at a time, always restarting, and when you get again these issues, you have located the problematic one.

If it doesn't solve the problem, or if you want to learn more about the subject, read also the knowledge base articles on [Firefox crashes](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_crashes) and [troubleshooting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Standard_diagnostic_-_Firefox).

Comment: I've disabled all the extensions and plugins and it keeps crashing

Comment: Using safe mode helps neither. And neither does cleaning everything and installing a fresh copy of Firefox. Tabs with other pages can work (to cause the fault) also. It also crashes after some time of active usage even when there are just a couple of tabs open. But I remember using over 50 tabs with no problems in the past (in older versions).

Comment: I had the same problem and had to delete my profile to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile-id>\crashes\events` (I guess they moved the location somewhen since nc4pk answer)

You may also be interested to [these variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Environment_variables_affecting_crash_reporting), for further tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, based on the installation:

- ~/.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports/
- ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports